# Как реализовать передачу массива из php в javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

Помогите реализовать передачу массива из `php` в `javascript`.
Из базы данных получаю массив:

```
Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 1867-09-16 [2] => Иванов [3] => Иван [4] => Иванович )
```

```
array_push ($arr,$id,$date_birth,$familia,$imya,$otchestvo);
```

А в javascript надо получить массив такого вида:

```js
{ id: 0, name: 'Иванов Иван Иванович', birthDate: '1867-09-16' }
```

Я уже перепробовал всё, что знал и что нашел в интернете:

```
let json = '<?php echo (json_encode($arr))?>';
let arr1 = JSON.parse(json);
```

Comment: `let json = <?php echo (json_encode($arr))?>;`

Comment: Проблема не в этом.  Ругается на кавычки 'Иванов Иван Иванович' которые обязательны.

Comment: Ошибка в консоли браузера есть какая-то?

Comment: Unexpected string (at  test.php: 227:57)  лишняя кавычка    name : ' ","Иванов Иван Иванович"," ' - а так как раз и получается то, что нужно 'Иванов Иван Иванович'.  Где-то что-то не так делаю, а что не пойму.

Comment: Ну а что происходит в test.php на указанной строке плюс несколько строк до\после?

Comment: Не совсем понял причём тут json.

Comment: Задам вопрос по другому. Может ли кто написать код как получить из этого :  array_push ($arr,$id,$date_birth,$familia,$imya,$otchestvo);     это :   { id: 0, name: 'Иванов Иван Иванович', birthDate: '1867-09-16' }

Comment: `json_encode(['name' => '', 'id' => '', ...])`

Comment: Полный тупик: создаю массив - array_push ($arr,'[{id:',$id,'birthDate:',$date_birth,'name:',$familia,$imya,$otchestvo,'},]');   далее  let arr1 = <?php echo ($arr)?>;    в итоге ошибка:  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at   строка:  let arr1 = <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>C:\Server\data\htdocs\ .  Ругается на <br />, как его убрать?

Comment: Что за дичь ты творишь. Вот простейший пример https://3v4l.org/OPbnf, сделай так же.

Comment: Всем СПАСИБО за участие и подсказки. Все оказалось намного проще: я решил, что в scripte (не мой) используется массив, поэтому у меня ничего не получалось, как я только не крутился, а оказалось что это строка $arr = implode($arr); и все пошло.